# TransactionScope rollback with Visual Basic.net and SQL Server 2008

Tags: .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2005, transactionscope

I'm learning how to use `transactionScope` with Visual Basic.net in Visual Studio 2008 and I'm trying to make and easy query updating some data and the launching an exception, but the `transactionScope` doesn't made the rollback, the data had been updated even the code doesn't made the `tran2.complete` sentence.

The exception appears when I execute the second query because the field idLegacy doesn't exist.

Can anyone help me?

```
        DB_MSSQL = New BBDD(ClassUtil.CadenaConexion_Destino)

        Using tran2 As New TransactionScope()
            Try
                Dim SqlPrueba As String = "UPDATE CAMPANIA_PEDIDOS set _idlegacy = -6 where Id = 151879"
                DB_MSSQL.dameDataSet(SqlPrueba)
                Dim SqlPrueba2 as String = "UPDATE CAMPANIA_PEDIDOS set idlegacy = -5 where Id = 151879"
                DB_MSSQL.dameDataSet(SqlPrueba2)
                tran2.Complete()
            Catch ex As TransactionAbortedException
                ClassUtil.PintaEnLog("Error al exportar pedido: " & ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To enlist automatically, a connection must be opened (or possibly created, but opened sounds more likely) **inside** the ambient transaction. For example:

```
    Using tran2 As New TransactionScope()
        Try
            DB_MSSQL = New BBDD(ClassUtil.CadenaConexion_Destino)
            Dim SqlPrueba As String = "UPDATE CAMPANIA_PEDIDOS set _idlegacy = -6 where Id = 151879"
            DB_MSSQL.dameDataSet(SqlPrueba)
            Dim SqlPrueba2 as String = "UPDATE CAMPANIA_PEDIDOS set idlegacy = -5 where Id = 151879"
            DB_MSSQL.dameDataSet(SqlPrueba2)
            tran2.Complete()
        Catch ex As TransactionAbortedException
            ClassUtil.PintaEnLog("Error al exportar pedido: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using
```

also, assuming that `DB_MSQL` encapsulates a connection, it probably needs to be disposed too, via `Using`.

Finally, I would strongly encourage you to use parameters instead of concatenation when building TSQL - it is much more efficient (the server can re-use the parsed query) and safer (SQL injection etc). If this is just for the example, then: no problem.

Comment: When I have put the DB_MSQL inside the using and exception appears that says ERROR [25S12] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Error in transacction distributed

Comment: @alberto_redo then you need to fix that error. Is DTC available, etc? Are the network ports open (see: dtcping). Actually I would *hope* that would use the LTM rather than DTC, but many of the pre-reqs are the same. Basically, that error tells you it is at least now *trying* to use the ambient transaction. Something is stopping it: so go fix that something. Or, use a regular SQL transaction - they are actually much more efficient than ambient transactions.

Comment: I'm trying to make the SQL transaction, but I need to create an SqlConection and I don't know how can I do it. ClassUtil.CadenaConexion_Destino returns this string "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=SRVSQLWEB.ASSECO.LOCAL\WEB01;UID=sa;PWD=xxxx;DATABASE=SimWeb-Desarrollo" How do I make the SQLConection with this?

Comment: @alberto_redo as a connection string that looks fine; that isn't the point though - there are various reasons why DTC might fail, hence why I mentioned "dtcping". Indeed, the subtleties of getting DTC working is a good reason to first consider using ADO.NET transactions instead of ambient transactions.